# react on Ajax response if multiple ids

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I receive Ajax response with multiple html element with dynamic ids and I want to react on them like if the user click on them.

```
$("#friend").keyup(function(){
        var friend = $(this).val();
        $("#friend_select").show();
        if(friend != ''){
            $('#friend_select').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#friend').css("overflow", "visible");
            $.ajax({

                url: "../system/challenge_engine.php",
                method: "post",
                data:{friend:friend},
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#friend_select').html(data);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#friend_select').html('');
            $('#friend_select').css("visibility", "hidden");

        }
    });
```

The php code:

```
<?php 
include_once("../includes/check_user.inc.php");
if($user_ok != true || $username == "") {
    exit();
}
$user = "";
$friend = $_POST["friend"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user1 LIKE '%$friend%' AND user2 = '$username' AND accepted = '1') OR (user1 = '$username'  AND user2 LIKE '%$friend%' AND accepted = '1')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($resultCheck > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if($row['user1'] == $username){
            $user .= '<p id="friend_'.$row['user2'].'" class="friend_name">'. $row['user2'].'</p>';
        }else{
            $user .= '<p id="friend_'.$row['user1'].'" class="friend_name">'. $row['user1'].'</p>';
        }
    }   
    echo $user;
}else{
     echo '<p>No result.</p>';
}
```

and here the rest html code:

```
<div class="select_friend">
    <label for="friend">Freund auswählen</label>
    <input id="friend" name="friend" class="friend" type="text" placeholder="Choose Friend...">
    <div id="friend_select" class="friend_select"></div>
</div>
```

I want that when a user clicks on a result of the dropdown menu than the input field value should change to the name of friend. I hope someone can help.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Check out jQuery's `.on()`-method for creating events: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: yeah.. I know. I written this fast and it is just on a local machine.. but thank you for the advice

Comment: Tip: Always think about security. Using prepared statements is simply just one or tow extra commands, so it's easy. That way you don't need to go back and rewrite stuff if you want to use it for real later.

Comment: So I dont need to change the code or something like that, but only the mysql stuff?

Comment: Basically just the sql-query and the call. Check the link I posted. It is so much easier than people first think.

Comment: Okay thank you again dude, I will. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .on method from jQuery. Here is the link: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Something like this:

$('.friend_name').on('click'. function (){ console.log( $( this ).text() ) })

Comment: Change it to: `$('body').on('click', '.friend_name', function (){ console.log( $( this ).text() ) })`. That way, all elements with `.friend_name` that gets added to the DOM later will also get the event. And this only needs to be registered once, directly in your `$(function()){   }`-call

Comment: but you saw at browser console? instead of console.log function try to use the alert function

Comment: the way Magnus written seems to work.. But is it the only way to do that

Comment: @Reebal - Sure, there are other ways, but they won't be "better" or "easier". This way is very easy, so why not use it?